# What's causing my stackoverflowerror in my maze solver?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I have to solve a maze using recursion and everything was going fine until I ran the program and ran into a stackoverflowerror. I've read a couple other questions on the site and they all say it's because of infinite recursion however none of their issues seem to be the exact same as mine.

my netID_maze.java file

```
import java.util.Random;

public class netID_Maze
{

int exitRow,
    entranceRow;
char[][] map = null;


// Method Name  : Maze (Constructor)
// Parameters  : None
// Partners  : None
// Description  : No Parameter Constructor for the maze
public netID_Maze()
{
    // omitted code generating a random maze

    setEntranceRow(rnger.nextInt(row - 2) + 1);
    setExitRow(rnger.nextInt(row - 2) + 1);

    map[getEntranceRow()][0] = '.';
    map[getExitRow()][column - 1] = '.'; 

} // end netID_Maze (without parameters)


// Method Name  : Maze (Constructor)
// Parameters  : exitTemp (int), entranceTemp(int), mapTemp (char[][])
// Partners  : None
// Description  : Parameter Constructor for the maze
public netID_Maze(char[][] mapTemp, int exitTemp, int entranceTemp)
{

    map = mapTemp;
    exitRow = exitTemp;
    entranceRow = entranceTemp;

} // end netID_Maze (with parameters)


// Method Name  : getCell
// Parameters  : row (int), column (int), character in cell (character)
// Partners  : None
// Returns : The character in the cell that's being called (character)
// Description  : Returns the character of the cell that's being called
public char getCell(int r, int c)
{
    return map[r][c];

} // end getCell()

// Method Name  : setCell
// Parameters  : row (int), column (int), character in cell (character)
// Partners  : None
// Returns : None
// Description  : Changes the character of the cell that's being called
public void setCell(int r, int c, char val)
{
    this.map[r][c] = val;

} // end setCell()

public int getEntranceRow ()
{
    return entranceRow;
}

public int getExitRow()
{
    return exitRow;
}

public void setEntranceRow(int entranceTemp)
{
    entranceRow = entranceTemp;
}

public void setExitRow(int exitTemp)
{
    exitRow = exitTemp;
}

public int getRows()
{
    return map.length;
}

public int getColumns()
{
    return map[1].length;
}

public boolean isExit(int r, int c)
{
    boolean isExit = false;

    if (getExitRow() == r && map[1].length - 1 == c)
    {
        isExit = true;
    }

    return isExit;
}

public boolean isEntrance(int r, int c)
{
    boolean isEntrance = false;

    if (getEntranceRow() == r && 0 == c)
    {
        isEntrance = true;
    }

    return isEntrance;
}

public boolean isOpen(int r, int c)
{

    boolean isOpen = true;

    if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= getRows() || c >= getColumns())
    {
        isOpen = false;
    }
    else if (map[r][c] == '.')
    {
        isOpen = false;
    }

    return isOpen;
}

}
```

and my netID_MazeSolver.java file

```
public class netID_MazeSolver {
int steps = 0;
netID_Maze maze = new netID_Maze();

public netID_MazeSolver(netID_Maze mazeTemp)
{
    setSteps(0);
    maze = mazeTemp;
}

public boolean solveMaze(int r, int c)
{
    //Finding whether Current Cell is outside the maze
    if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= maze.getRows() || c >= maze.getColumns()) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Finding whether the current cell is the exit
    if (maze.isExit(r,c) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    //Finding whether current cell is NOT open
    if (maze.isOpen(r,c) == false)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Setting current cell as part of the solution path


    //Finding out whether solve maze(cell below current) == true
    if (solveMaze(r - 1,c) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    //Finding out whether solve maze(cell to the right of current) == true
    if (solveMaze(r,c + 1) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    //Finding out whether solve maze(cell to the left of current) == true
    if (solveMaze(r,c - 1) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    //Finding out whether solve maze(cell above current) == true
    if (solveMaze(r + 1,c) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    //setting current cell to NOT part of the solution path


    return false;

}

public void setSteps(int stepsTemp)
{
    steps = stepsTemp;
}

public int getSteps()
{
    return steps;
}

}
```

The actual error just keeps repeating:
        at netID_MazeSolver.solveMaze(netID_MazeSolver.java:53)
        at netID_MazeSolver.solveMaze(netID_MazeSolver.java:71)

Comment: Where's your recursion occurring? You possibly have a faulty stopping condition. Edit: it's your solveMaze method -- time to use a debugger to find out why you're recursing forever.

Comment: Alright I'll look through that method, thanks.

Comment: This is one of those times I love to visualize the problem and solution.  Define the map on paper (and make a copy in your code).  Use a debugger to step through your code and see if the logic in your code is the same you would use for the given point...

Comment: Please do not delete all code - the question is is useless without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic mistake you made, was that you don't set any flags for visited cells. Due to this, your algorithm can visit the same cell again and again. If your generated maze contains any cycles, you're pretty likely to end up in an endlessloop causing a stackoverflow. And btw, you don't need, to write `if(maze.isOpen(r , c) == true)`. `if(maze.isOpen(r , c))` gives the same result with less code.

Comment: Thank you! I set the comment up for tagging visited cells but as you can see I never actually wrote the code. Silly mistake on my half. And yes, I do know that but my teacher prefers it the other way for some odd reason. Either way thanks again!